# json_decode is not working on a string with \ in it

Tags: escaping, json

I have a  a ajax call in which I am sending json_string as a post variable.   which I am decoding using json_decode at server,  but  it fails  when the string contains  \ in it.

```
    $arr = array("data-0"=>'{"id":"Ch35ZWIjfMwG5EUWlVJvGJGWeZi+j+v27AGX+qtUZ14=","pos_x1":"0","pos_y1":"0"}',
                "data-1"=>'{"id":"h+ZjS3+FBoEebtxsHGmgbr\Dy8zTmgrLjhcZH8z3enpw=","pos_x1":"1","pos_y1":"152"}');

foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
print_r(json_decode($val,true));
```

When I  try running the above,  The second value is not being decoded.

The "id" value is encrypted text, so have no control on it.

Tried addslashes, but no use.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `\D` is not a valid escape sequence. `addslashes` will put slashes before all the `"`s, which will just make it worse.

Instead, consider fixing your JSON source - I know you said it's encrypted text, but that doesn't mean you can't properly `json_encode` it in the first place to get your data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am already making use of JSON.stringify(data) in Javascript before passing the data to server. Do I need to encode even at individual variable level as well?